# Soundcloud API using AudioManager events

Tags: api, soundcloud, rtmp, soundmanager2, android-audiomanager

I have been working with the soundcloud api. If your familiar with it, you will know that for streaming songs from their api they have a call(SC.stream) that returns an audioManager object.  I think this is their proprietary media player that supports rtmp.  Unfortunately their documentation only mentions the old media player used for streaming with the api: soundManager2.  My question is does anyone no how to implement event handlers.  I see that the player object has a .bind() method. But I don't have the event syntax.  Anyone know???

The equivalent events I need are: onplay, onpause, onerror, ontimechange, onended

this is the audioManager source code I believe: https://connect.soundcloud.com/audiomanager/audiomanager.js

Help greatly apreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: come on, someone must know. where you at soundcloud..

Answer (score 0):

One way you can this could be this:

```
  SC.stream("/tracks/" + track.id, { 
        autoPlay: true,
            whileplaying: function () {
            console.log("track is playing - whileplaying");}, 
        ontimedcomments: function(comments){ 
            console.log("First Comment at this timestamp", comments[0].body); }, 
        onplay: function () {
            console.log("track is playing - onplay");},
        onerror: function () {
            alert("error");}, 
        ontimechanged: function () {
            alert("time has changed");}, 
        onended: function () {
            alert("track ended");}, 
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/gmqz9gp4/

Comment: The problem is I don't know the correct syntax for the event handler parameters ie. onplay, onerror, etc

Comment: Isnt it in the sketch?

Comment: Take a look on the code above, i guess its the code you are looking for? If not, pls share yours to help you further.

Comment: Ok I see.  The event names in the code were so similar to the event names I just guessed I did not think they were right.  My bad. But if they are correct why doesn't the jsfiddle play any song or log anything to the console?